# Manejando una BD con muchos datos ( 2 millones )

Tags: javascript, python, base-de-datos

Tengo una BD con paises, productos,año y costos de importacion, y me quiero crear una pagina o aplicacion para Desktop, en la cual pueda hacer busquedas a partir de paises y años, estaba pensando en montarla en PHPMyAdmin pero al momento que la intento cargar es demasiado pesada(1.8GB) y la he dejado por mas de 5 horas y se termina colgando el programa. Me gustaria saber de que manera puedo manejar tantos datos. Ya sea con Python,JS, Java ( creo que seria muy complejo ).

Comment: de todos los lenguajes que mencionas con cual tienes mas experiencia practica? de ahi partir para poder establecer una solución

Comment: pues el primer detalle no es el lenguaje con el que trabajaras el backend si no como importar la base de datos

Comment: Con los tres he trabajado de la misma manera, pero Python lo he ocupado para manejar datos, pero nunca tantos datos e intentando hacer consultas hacia una BD, he ahí el porque no se como abordar este problema.

Comment: la calidad en los tiempos de consulta no depende meramente del lenguaje si no de la estructura de las mismas, las relaciones entre ellas, si tienen índices creados los columnas que vas a  usar como filtros de búsquedas, además aunque la cantidad de datos es grande dudo mucho que se los vayas a mostrar todos al usuario, generalmente solo se hace paginación de una cantidad x que vas a mostrar

Comment: Una base de datos relacional de ese tamaño podría empezar a degradar su performance a medida que crece, considera utilizar una base no relacional para mantener el rendimiento.

Comment: @jirungaray eso no es así; la calidad de la misma no depende si es o no relacional si no la calidad de las queries en forma de si estan o no indexadas o si usan window functions, si la srelaciones entre tablas son lógicas pero no por que sean relacionales, además las bases de datos no relacionales no son para todos los escenarios lo mismo que las relacionales

Comment: Para este tipo de cargas lo que "necesitas" usar son las MySql GuiTools, son herramientas algo antiguas, pero para trabajos de carga y respaldo como este, eran una maravilla. Con el tiempo Oracle las remplazó con Workbench, pero te hablo por experiencia, probablemente es lo único que te ayudará. Aquí te dejo el [link](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/gui/)

Comment: No creo que ni PHPMyAdmin ni ninguna otra interfaz gráfica sea la mejor opción para manejar grandes cantidades de datos. Considero que la importación de los datos conviene que la hagas por línea de comandos directamente es lo más rapido y más seguro. En MySQL puedes importar cualquier base de datos grande por línea de comando con una rapidez considerable con respecto a cualquier interfaz gráfica. Luego la fluidez en el manejo de datos una vez la importación hecha depende como ya se ha dicho, de los índices en la BD y de que escribas un código optimizado para obtener/mostrar los datos.

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que quieres inicialmente es importar la base de datos no uses programas, ve al terminal y ejecuta

```
mysql -u root -p nombre_base_datos < fichero.sql
```

Nos preguntrará la contraseña para el usuario que indiquemos (en el ejemplo anterior “root”) y una vez conectados empezará a importar todo.

Comment: Best answer! +1

Comment: Eso suena bien, pero el modulo "mysql" es como parte de que libreria? . Yo estoy usando Windows, ¿Es algun comando de Unix?

Comment: @MemoVaraD.Gante MySQL es el servidor de base de datos que usa PHPMyAdmin y está disponible en todas las plataformas

Answer (score 1):

Primero mencionas PHPMyAdmin y después lenguajes.

**Para importar / exportar los datos de una base de datos ya existente en MySQL** te recomiendo el MySQL Workbench lo utilice bastante veces, para bases de datos de entre 300 ~ 500mb y da unos resultados excelentes en cuanto a velocidad y seguimiento de la operatoria.

**El método anterior sirve cuando la importación / exportación no requiere de ninguna adaptación**, es decir las estructuras de las tablas y el contenido de los registros permanece intacto.
Sí necesitas realizar una importación modificando estructuras de tablas o registros, en mi experiencia personal siempre lo realicé a través de PHP nativo.

Ahora sí la pregunta esta enfocada en **desarrollar una aplicación teniendo una base de datos ya existente**, que alguien me contradiga pero la mayoría de lenguajes deberían ser iguales de óptimo la diferencia en cuanto a velocidad de las consultas y demás estará dada por la organización correctas de las tablas, sus relaciones, su procesamiento, el hardware, pero no es que haya un lenguaje mejor o peor para tratar bases de datos.

Saludos.

-EDIT-

El manejo del Workbench es bastante intuitivo, aunque adjunto algunas capturas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la sección Data Export y Data Import / Restore aparecen las bases de datos alojadas en este caso en localhost y la posibilidad

Además adjunto un ejemplo de como realizar una **migración personalizada a través de PHP**, en este caso desde SQL Server -> MySQL y realizando variaciones en los registros.

```
<?php
//Creo un vector de provincias.
$provincias = array();

//PARAMETROS DE LA BASE DE DATOS.
$serverName = "direccion"; // Direccion de la base de datos.
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"base_datos", "UID"=>"usuario", "PWD"=>"password", "ReturnDatesAsStrings" => true);

//CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS Y DETECCION DE ERRORES EN LA CONEXION.
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo); //Ejecuto la conexión a la base de datos.
if($conn) // Si la conexión fue exitosa.
  echo "Conexión con SQL Server establecida.<br />";
else //Si hubo errores, informo el tipo de error y termino la ejecución.
{ 
   echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

//PRIMERO OBTENGO LA CANTIDAD DE REGISTROS DE LA TABLA
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Ms_Provincias
WHERE idProvincia NOT IN(25,26,27,29,30,33,36,37,38,39)";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql); // Ejecuto la consulta.
if($stmt === false) // Si la consulta tuvo un error.
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

$numFields = sqlsrv_num_fields($stmt); // Numero de registros.

while(sqlsrv_fetch($stmt)) { //Recorro los registros.
   for($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++) { //Recorro las columnas del registro.
    if($i==0)
      $provincia['id'] = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, $i);
    else if($i==1)
      $provincia['nombre'] = sanear_string(sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, $i)); // Acentos son saneados.
    else if($i==2)
      $provincia['pais_id'] = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, $i);
    else if($i==3)
    {
      else if(sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, $i) == 0)
        $provincia['estado'] = 1;
      else if(sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, $i) == 1)
        $provincia['estado'] = 0;
    }  
     $provincia['campo_particular'] = intval("1");
   }
  array_push($provincias, $provincia); //Agrego el elemento anterior al array.
}
echo count($provincias); //Esto es para comprobar el array esta lleno de registros.
sqlsrv_close($conn); //Cierro la conexión.


//TRATAMIENTO DE DATOS.

for($i=0;$i<count($provincias);$i++)
{
  for($j=0;$j<count($provincias);$j++)
  {
        if(strtoupper($provincias[$i]['nombre']) == strtoupper($provincias[$j]['nombre']) && ($i!=$j)) // Nombres son saneados.
          {
              unset($provincias[$j]); // Elimino el elemento que cumple la condicion de duplicado.
              $provincias = array_values($provincias); //Arreglo los indices del array, no confundir con el ID de provincia.
          }
  }
            echo "<br>";
          echo $provincias[$i]['nombre'];
}
echo "<br>";
echo count($provincias); //Esto es para comprobar el array esta lleno de registros.

//UNA VEZ QUE TENGO LOS DATOS DE LA BASE VIEJA, VOY A LA BASE NUEVA Y LOS GUARDO.

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", 'basededatos');

if(!$conn) 
    die("Conexion con MySQL invalida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
else
  echo "Conexion con MySQL correcta";

if(is_array($provincias)){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO provincias (id, nombre, pais_id, campo_particular, estado) values "; // Genero la estructura de la consulta.
    $valuesArr = array(); //Vector auxiliar.
    foreach($provincias as $row){ //Recorro el vector principal.
        $id = (int)($row['id']);
        $nombre = $row['nombre'];
        $pais_id = $row['pais_id'];
        $campo_particular = (int)($row['campo_particular']);
        $estado = (int) $row['estado'];

        $valuesArr[] = "('$id', '$nombre', '$pais_id', '$campo_particular', '$estado')";
    }
    $sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or exit(mysqli_error($conn)); //Ejecuto la consulta.
}
?>
```

Comment: incluso para mejorar tu respuesta yo te recomendaría dejaras los pasos claros y concisos sobre como hacer la importación con workbench como tu mismo lo mencionas de tal manera que si otro usuario entra y consulta le sea fácil comprender el proceso

Comment: Agregué información adicional, aunque creería que al menos la explicación de como utilizar el Workbench no es necesaria, es un software muy intuitivo. Saludos.

Comment: la idea de Stack Over Flow es dar respuestas completas que sirvan como guia a quien consulte amigo, imagina que llega un novato que nunca lo ha usado le va a servir mas pasos detallados que solo un texto genérico

Comment: Considero que para importar grandes cantidades de datos no hay nada mejor que hacerlo por línea de comandos directamente, prescindiendo de cualquier interfaz gráfica.