# ¿Como insertar valor de un array con $_SESSION en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hola tengo una variable SESSION que contiene estos datos(id,nombre,quantity,precio) es un carrito de compras, entonces cuando me traigo esta variable con todo el contenido a mi otra página no se como insertar la cantidad que trae este array en los campos específicos de mi tabla los cuales tiene estos campos (Nombre,Direccion,Email,Telefono, Taco_pastor,Taco_suadero,Torta_pastor,Torta_suadero,Refresco,Jugo,Total,Fecha)
en ese orden, lo que yo quiero es que me inserte la cantidad que haya pedido el usuario y que en caso de que no tenga una cantidad lo ponga como cero en mi tabla

lo he intentado con foreach e ifs para compararlos mediante el value de los inputs(donde se ven bien) pero hasta ahora esto no me funciona y solo me imprime la cantidad en "Torta_suadero"

```
foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $product):

$cant=$_POST['nombre'];

if ($cant=='Taco_pastor') {

$tacop2= $product['quantity'];

} else {

$tacop2=0;

}

if ($cant=='Taco_suadero') {

$tacosu2= $product['quantity'];

} else {

$tacosu2=0;

}

if ($cant=='Torta_pastor') {

$tortap2= $product['quantity'];

} else {

$tortap2=0;

}

if ($cant=='Torta_suadero') {

$tortasu2= $product['quantity'];

} else {

$tortasu2=0;

}

if ($cant=='Refresco') {

$refresco2= $product['quantity'];

} else {

$refresco2=0;

}

if ($cant=='Jugo') {

$jugo2= $product['quantity'];

} else {

$jugo2=0;

}

endforeach;

if(!$error){
echo '';
$sql = "insert into pedidos(Nombre,Direccion,Email,Telefono, Taco_pastor,Taco_suadero,Torta_pastor,Torta_suadero,Jugo,Refresco,Total,Fecha)
               values('$cliente', '$dir2', '$email2', '$tel2', '$tacop2','$tacosu2','$tortap2','$tortasu2','$jugo2','$refresco2','$total2','$fecha')";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
$successMsg = 'SU PEDIDO A SIDO TOMADO EN UN MOMENTO LE LLEGARA A SU DOMICILIO GRACIAS!!!!'; 
}else{
echo 'Error '.mysqli_error($conn);
}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya le hiciste un var_dum($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] para saber que tantos datos esta trrayendo ?

Comment: Hola, como primera medida te recomendaría que realices un print_r de $_SESSION['shopping_cart'] al principio de la página seguido de un exit(); y veas sí realmente el contenido esta almacenado correctamente.

Comment: @JuanjooTocino me esta imprimiendo los valores que necesito con print_r

Comment: Sí no te es mucha molestia podrías sacar captura de pantalla o copiar el código impreso por el print_r, solo para ver la estructura y saber como recorrerlo correctamente.

Comment: @srJJ con var_dump me trae la información que necesito de igual forma pero ahora no se como capturar esa información en mis diferentes campos, ni que cuando no traiga algún producto lo imprima en 0

Comment: @JuanjooTocino listo ya edite mi pregunta con la img

Answer (score 1):

Podrías manipular los datos algo así:

```
<?php
$shopping_cart = $_SESSION['shopping_cart'];

foreach($shopping_cart as $element)
{
    $nombre = $element['nombre'];
    $precio = $element['precio'];
    $quantity = $element['quantity'];
    $sql = "insert into pedidos(Nombre,Direccion,Email,Telefono, Taco_pastor,Taco_suadero,Torta_pastor,Torta_suadero,Jugo,Refresco,Total,Fecha)
               values('$cliente', '$dir2', '$email2', '$tel2', '$tacop2','$tacosu2','$tortap2','$tortasu2','$jugo2','$refresco2','$total2','$fecha')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
        $successMsg = 'SU PEDIDO A SIDO TOMADO EN UN MOMENTO LE LLEGARA A SU DOMICILIO GRACIAS!!!!'; 
    else
        echo 'Error '.mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

No agregué la lógica del problema, pero en $nombre, $precio, $quantity, ya estarían las variables para tomar la decisión.
El código no es del todo óptimo ya que se realiza un insert por cada producto, mientra que se podría realizar un solo insert en masa por así decirlo.

--EDIT--

Para complementar, [en este post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/186419/manejando-una-bd-con-muchos-datos-2-millones/186422#186422), después del if(is_array()) esta implementada la manera de realizar un INSERT masivo, por sí te interesa.

Comment: gracias al final pues tuve que hacerlo de esa forma que me creara los registros dependiendo de cada productos que haya pedido, no era justo lo que quería, pero de igual forma sirvió en un rato pongo como quedo el codigo final para quien le sirva

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que te diría es que viendo la consulta del insert tu tabla tiene un mal diseño, relacionas los productos con el nombre del cliente, en lugar del id único,  ¿que sucede si hay 2 cliente que se llaman igual?

Este caso debería ser una relación muchos a muchos entre `usuarios`/`clientes` y `detalles_pedidos`, dando lugar a una tabla intermedia `pedidos`

En cualquier caso cuando necesitas insertar en la bd, la recomendación es utilizar sentencias preparadas, para evitar problemas de inyección sql, las sentencias preparadas también nos facilitan insertar datos de forma masiva.

Una vez explicado esto pasemos aún ejemplo básico

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "world");

/* comprobar la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Preparar una sentencia INSERT */
$consulta = "INSERT INTO pedido (id_cliente, id_articulo, cantidad, precio) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$sentencia = $mysqli->prepare($consulta);

$sentencia->bind_param("iiis", $id_cliente, $id_articulo, $cantidad,$precio);

//una vez preparada la consulta podemos recorrer el Array he ir insertando
foreach($cesta as $key => $value){
    $id_cliente = $value['id_cliente'];
    $id_articulo = $value['id_articulo'];
    $cantidad = $value['cantidad'];
    $precio = $value['precio'];

    /* Ejecutar la sentencia */
    $sentencia->execute();
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Gracias eso me da una idea mas, de como habría quedado mejor mi BD, es que como en este caso para los pedidos no tengo usuarios ya registrados, pues lo que hago es que desde el formulario me pongan todos sus datos por eso quería que en un solo insert me pusiera estos datos que necesito